# grub2win does not boot the ISO image "Semicode OS"

Tags: linux, grub2

I'm using Grub2Win
and I defined it manually in the "grub.cfg" file 
to boot from "3.0 Linux Lite" & "Ubuntu Mate 16.0"
ISO Files, and it worked.

but when I tried to do the same operation
with "SemiCode OS" ISO, it doesn't work.

when I run, it looks like it work's
show's a splash screen and all
until it runs some script(don't remember name)
and gives this error:

```
"init: Error line 3 "dev/sr0" medium not Found"
```

I don't know what is the problem
I tried to set the root manually with:

```
set root='hd0,gpt3'
```

where gpt3 is the partition
where the ISO is located
but it still gives me the same error.

Here is the "Semicode OS" startup code in "grub.cfg":

```
menuentry   'Try SemiCode OS Beta without installing' --class isoboot --class icon-linux --class custom_004  {
    set gfxpayload=keep

clear
    set root='hd0,gpt3'
    set gfxpayload=keep
    set isopath='/Linux/SemiCode[coding]/SemiCodeOS-dist.iso'
    set kernelpath='/casper/vmlinuz'
    set bootparms='/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash --'
    set initrdpath='/casper/initrd.gz'

#

g2wisoboot                                          # Run the g2wisoboot function

#
# end-custom-code
}
```

all the path's are correct i checked!
but still it gives me the same Error:

```
"init: Error line 3 "dev/sr0" medium not Found"
```

I have no idea why this happens.

I'm using Win7 with SP1
Intel i3 CPU, m.b: Asus
8GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

You have to load iso with a loop function in grub.

Check the menuentry you have for ubuntu mate 16.

I think you can find suggestion how to load iso loop.